# How to run .inp file for Ansys from Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder

I would like to run/start ansys .inp file from Spyder. I´ve managed to start to app but how to open it with specific file with defined path?
Appreciate the help, thank you.

```
import os
    import subprocess

    #ansys path =""
    os.startfile(ansys_path)

    #path to the input file
    input_file = ""
    command = f'"{ansys_path}" -b -i "{input_file}"'
    os.system(command)
```

this just starts the ansys app

Answer (score 0):

To run an Ansys input file (.inp) from Spyder, you can use the following steps. Please note that these instructions assume you have Ansys installed on your system and Spyder configured properly.

Open Spyder:

Launch the Spyder IDE on your computer.
Create or Open a Python Script:

Create a new Python script or open an existing one in Spyder.
Write Python Script to Execute Ansys:

Write a Python script in Spyder to execute Ansys using the subprocess module.
Save the Python Script:

Save the Python script with a .py extension.
Run the Python Script:

Click on the "Run" button in Spyder to execute the Python script.
Review Output:

Check the Spyder console for any output or error messages from the Ansys execution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy